# Longtable overlaps with content from second column of next page

Tags: longtable

My `longtable` overlaps with the content of the second column of the next page, while the first column of the next page is pushed to start after the end of the `longtable` nicely.

[image]

Here is my table's code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[t]{|l|c|l|}
\caption{Class distribution of the semantic entities in DUFFR dataset and baseline model classes mapping.} \label{table:mapping} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Original Class}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Number of Samples}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Mapped to}} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Original Class}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Number of Samples}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Mapped to}} \\ \hline
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
date & 699 & date \\ 
organization & 432 & organization \\ 
skill\_entry & 378 & entry \\ 
section\_title & 267 & section\_title \\ 
date\_range & 247 & date\_range \\ 
experience\_entry & 218 & entry \\ 
job\_title & 202 & job\_title \\ 
training\_title & 152 & name \\ 
experience\_description & 148 & description \\ 
training\_entry & 138 & entry \\ 
education\_certificate\_name & 89 & name \\ 
experience\_section & 82 & section \\ 
certificate\_name & 80 & name \\ 
achievement\_entry & 77 & entry \\ 
education\_entry & 74 & entry \\ 
certificate\_entry & 74 & entry \\ 
country & 71 & country \\ 
personal\_info\_section & 58 & section \\ 
phone\_num & 55 & phone\_num \\ 
language\_name & 55 & language\_name \\ 
language\_proficiency & 53 & language\_proficiency \\ 
personal\_other & 52 & details \\ 
language\_entry & 51 & entry \\ 
address & 48 & address \\ 
experience\_other & 45 & details \\ 
skills\_section & 45 & section \\ 
person\_name & 40 & person\_name \\ 
email & 38 & email \\ 
education\_section & 37 & section \\ 
datetime\_word & 36 & date \\ 
personal\_bio & 35 & description \\ 
training\_section & 31 & section \\ 
other & 27 & other \\ 
project\_title & 27 & name \\ 
training\_additional\_info & 25 & details \\ 
languages\_section & 24 & section \\ 
online\_presence\_link & 22 & online\_presence\_link \\ 
education\_field\_of\_study & 21 & education\_field\_of\_study \\ 
project\_description & 17 & description \\ 
education\_grade & 17 & education\_grade \\ 
personal\_image & 17 & personal\_image \\ 
education\_additional\_info & 12 & details \\ 
certificates\_section & 12 & section \\ 
education\_studied\_subjects & 9 & details \\ 
projects\_section & 7 & section \\ 
column & 6 & column \\ 
project\_entry & 5 & entry \\ 
language\_level\_justification & 3 & language\_level\_justification \\ 
attachment & 2 & attachment \\ 
achievement\_description & 1 & description \\ 
certificate\_additional\_info & 1 & details \\ 
project\_other & 1 & details \\

\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Latex is complex, and many important things do follow or were not placed right after the \documentclass statement. So, please make your code complete, so that: a) we can copy& run it, b) it still shows your problem, c) is stripped off anything which does not contribute to your problem.

Comment: longable is not supported in two column documents (and should never be in   `center`) how didyou generate a two column example?